# How can I make ANSI encoded text file by using pl/sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm currently making a procedure to create a text file by using PL/SQL.

However, Text file is encoded only UTF-8. but I need to be ANSI encoded text file because of using at MS Excel.
(If UTF-8 file is loaded at Excel, Korean characters are crashed.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHcV1.jpg)

Below is my source.

How can I solve this problem?

---

```
  CURSOR SQL_CUR IS
        SELECT DATA_S VAR_DATA
        FROM A_TABLE ;



V_FILE := PARAM_A_NUM || '_' || PARAM_C_NUM || '.TXT';

V_OUTPUT := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIRECTORY', V_FILE, 'w');

  FOR V_CUR IN SQL_CUR LOOP

    V_RESULT := V_CUR.VAR_DATA;
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_OUTPUT, V_RESULT);

  END LOOP; 

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_OUTPUT);

 EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID PATH');
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID MODE');
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID OPERATION');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a file with `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` then Oracle opens the file in database character set which is by default `AL32UTF8` nowadays.

Either change encoding of the file with an external application afterwards (e.g. Java tool [native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html)) or use `UTL_FILE.FOPEN(..., open_mode => 'wb')` in order to write byte values.

Writing would be (not tested):

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_OUTPUT, CONVERT(V_RESULT, 'KO16MSWIN949'));
```